# GLTF and USDZ repeat and scale texture problem (tiling texture)

Tags: blender, arkit, gltf, usdz

We're trying to do tiling textures for AR Quick Look (iOS in USDZ (pixar) format), but issuing a problem.

What we have:

1. Project in the blender, where we use scaling texture via mapping (screen below) and everything looks fine like it is tiled properly.
2. When I do export in GLTF 2.0 you can see, that texture is not scaled (scale should be 100, 100) and that is why it looks bad. Doing not tiled textures for (for example) roads, is bad idea, so, that is why i'm using it.
3. The same goes to usdz.But i think that it is because of GLTF format

Not sure if while exporting from blender to gltf i should do something correctly

[image: this is how scale looks in blender]

[image: this is the image of how tiling and scale looks correctly]

[image: this is how it looks in GLTF, no scale, nothing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question might be better suited for Blender SE, not here.

The glTF exporter is looking for a shader node called "UV Map" instead of that "Texture Coordinate" node you have there.  I realize the names are almost synonymous, but the "UV Map" node has a chooser for which UV Map, and that's what the exporter wants to find.  (For more detail, [there is documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/import_export/io_scene_gltf2.html#uv-mapping).)

Also I don't know if glTF export supports that little splitter node you have in your graph there.  Try drawing individual lines from the "mapping" box to each of the image textures.